# How to add additional parameter in existing constructor. C++ ASIO

Tags: c++, asio

I need help on constructing the endpoint with 3 arguements. Currently "IP Address" & "Port" are there in the constructor. But i need to include an integer arguement to identify the connection. Ideally as mentioned below.
`asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(asio::ip::make_address("127.0.0.1", ec), 7497, clientId = 0);`

Could you please help whether i have to modify the base class or can i inherit the base class & add this arguement? if inheriting is easy, please guide me on that.

```
int main(int argc)
{
    int clientId = 0;
    asio::error_code ec;
    // Create a "context" - essentially the platform specific interface
    asio::io_context context;
    // Get th addres of somewhere w wish to connect to 
    asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(asio::ip::make_address("127.0.0.1", ec), 7497);
    // Create a socket, the context will deliver the implementation
    asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(context);
    // tell socket to try and connect
    socket.connect(endpoint, ec);
    if (!ec)
    {
        std::cout << "Conected!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to connect to address:\n" << ec.message() << std::endl;
    }
    if (socket.is_open())
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Inherited class:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

#ifdef _WIN32
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0A00
#endif
#define ASIO_STANDALONE
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <asio/ts/buffer.hpp>
#include <asio/ts/internet.hpp>


// Get th addres of somewhere w wish to connect to 
class clien : public asio::ip::tcp::endpoint, asio::ip::address
{
public:
    typedef asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint;
    char asio::ip::address;

    int clientId;

    //clien(int cid);

    clien(str ep, int p, int cid) : asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(ep), char asio::ip::address, int cid;
    {
        clientId = cid;
    }
};
```

Comment: is the class a class you have made? if not then inheritance is the only (reasonable) way.

Comment: Hi, No, the class is from ASIO header files. I am trying to inherit the base class & deriving a child class. But I am new to C++ & struggling. So, far I have made this code - please refer it in Inherited class section.

Answer (score 0):

since the class overloading way look to be the easiest:

```cpp
class clien : public asio::ip::tcp::endpoint {
                                                 // inherit endpoint (because it the class you want to change)
    protected:
        
         int __cid; // the id
    public:
         int clientId() const { return __cid; }  // getter
         void clientId(int cid) { __cid = cid; } // setter 

    clien(str ep, int p, int cid) :
        asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(ep, p),          // construct the actual endpoint
        __cid(cid){}                             // set the cid
};
```

i'm not familiar with the library so some type (for the constructor) might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new type  using endpoint and id

```cpp
struct MyEndpoint{
  asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint{};
  int someId{};  
}
```

Create the endpoint

```cpp
auto const someId = 42;
auto myEndpoint = MyEndpoint{ .endpoint = { boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4 (), 7497 }, .someId = someId };
```

Now you can get the id and the endpoint

```cpp
myEndpoint.someId;   // To get the id
myEndpoint.endpoint; // To get the endpoint
```

Another idea is to make a pair of id and endpoint

```cpp
auto const someId=42;
auto idAndEndpoint= std::make_pair(someId, asio::ip::tcp::endpoint{(asio::ip::make_address("127.0.0.1", ec), 7497)});
```

Now you can get the id and the endpoint

```cpp
auto &[id, endpoint] = idAndEndpoint;
```